# Getting http response exactly after 3.8 minutes with status code 500 OK

Tags: http, azure, web

I'm sending a http request to a web app which is hosted on Azure, the request needs more than 1 hour to complete. After I send the request in Chrome, I use F12 to check the Network status. The request returned with status code 500 OK every time, and the time used is exactly 3.8 minutes.
I have remote debugged this web app and find out the code is running perfectly fine, and there is not a single exception indicating the 500 OK error, but the browser just returned 500 OK.
I have also googled a lot. But due to the strange status code "500 OK", I couldn't find anything useful. 3.8 minutes appears like some time-relevant settings, so I tried setting executionTimeout in httpRuntime tag in Web.config, and also tried ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive, neither of these work.
Has anyone come across situation like this?

Comment: Please mark as answer if correct.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try it out, but why 3.8 minutes and 500 OK?

Comment: Its hard to tell without seeing your actual code.  Can you post that as well as where it runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with your Azure architecture design.  Any process that takes more than 5 seconds to complete should be processed on a different server.

Your architecture should include
1.  Azure Web App with rest endpoint
2.  Azure WebJob bound to a queue
3.  Azure Storage Queue (input)
4.  Azure Storage Blob (output).

incoming request should place the message on the queue with appropriate parameters.  The webjob should be bound to the queue watching for messages.  When a message is received, it processes, then puts the response on the output blob.

Your application should make a request for "is done processing", which looks at the blob for the expected id of the request.

To keep tabs on progress, you can keep a table in table storage or SQL that keeps tabs on process status (pending, processing, complete, received).

This architecture will allow your application to scale significantly better and increase your performance as well as provide proper responses.

Hope That Helps